# Is there way to assign and break within the block?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I know I can write it this way successfully:

```
def test_find_first_multiple_of_3
  numbers = [2, 8, 9, 27, 24, 5]
  found = nil
  numbers.each do |number|
    if number % 3 == 0
      found = number
      break
    end
  end
  assert_equal 9, found
end
```

Is there anyway to do within the block?  What am I missing? Or is just not possible?

```
numbers.each { |n| n % 3 == 0 ? (found = n then break) : nil }

def test_find_first_multiple_of_3
  numbers = [2, 8, 9, 27, 24, 5]
  found = nil
  numbers.each { |n| n % 3 == 0 ? (found = n then break) : nil }
  assert_equal 9, found
end
```

Comment: Don't do things like `(found = n then break)`. Mixing assignments in conditional tests hurt readability and maintenance as they look like unintentional assignments, and in production code that breaks at 3AM those little programming choices can really irritate co-workers. Just because we can write terse code doesn't mean we should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by other answers, there are other ruby ways to accomplish your algorithm goal, like using the `.find` method:

```
found = numbers.find { |n| (n % 3).zero? }
```

This way, you don't need to break your loop.

But, **specifically answering your question**, there are some ways to break the loop in the same line, if you want so:

- use `;` (multiple statements separator):

  ```
  numbers.each { |n| n % 3 == 0 ? (found = n; break) : nil }
  ```
- or put your assigment after break, that works too:

  ```
  numbers.each { |n| n % 3 == 0 ? (break found = n) : nil }
  ```

I just used your code in the example, but, again, that's not a good pratice, because, as well pointed by  @the Tin Man, *"hurts readability and maintenance"*.

Also, as pointed by @akuhn, you don't need to use ternary here. You can simply use:

```
numbers.each { |n| break found = n if n % 3 == 0 }
```

**** EDITED** to include suggestions from @the Tin Man, @akuhn and @Eric Duminil, in order to warn OP that there are other alternatives to run his task, that doesn't need to break loop. The original answer was written just to answer OP's question specifically (one line break loop), without the code structure concern.

Comment: Be careful using a ternary statement with anything more complex than a simple value in a branch as it hurts readability and maintenance. Instead use a standard `if`/`else`. Ternary statements should be very simple.

Comment: No need for a ternary if, just do `numbers.each { |n| break found = n if n % 3 == 0 }`

Comment: Sorry to say this : It might be what the OP wanted to know, but this is the least Ruby-ish and readable answer here.

Comment: You guys are right. I just tried to show how to concatenate statements (OP question), regardless the algorithm structure, just for learning purposes. I'll edit with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

With common Ruby idioms your can write:

```
def test_find_first_multiple_of_3
  numbers = [2, 8, 9, 27, 24, 5]
  found = numbers.find { |n| (n % 3).zero? }

  assert_equal 9, found
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both `break` and `next` take an argument.

For your example though, best use `find`

```
 founds = numbers.find { |n| n % 3 == 0 }
```

Generally in Ruby there is rarely a reason to `break` out of a loop.

You can typically use `find` or any of the other functions provided by the Enumerable module, like `take_while` and `drop_while`…

Answer (score 0):

You can use the enumerable method [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to find the first item that matches. Usually you will want to use enumerable methods like `cycle`, `detect`, `each`, `reject`, and others to make the code more compact while remaining understandable:

```
def test_find_first_multiple_of_3
  numbers = [2, 8, 9, 27, 24, 5]
  found = numbers.find { |number| number % 3 == 0 }
  assert_equal 9, found
end
```

Comment: Understood.  Thanks Rudolf.  For this particular situation, I only wanted to use the each method.  I should stated within my question.  My mistake.